# Printing image on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown selector in my HTML and I need to print out an image that is linked to a selection. But I have no idea how to start that.

```html
<input type="text" id="TextVeld" class="form-control" placeholder="get value on option select">

<br><br>

<select name="cars" id="TextShow" class="form-control">
  <option value="Pizza0">Kies je pizza</option>
  <option value="Pizza1">Margherita</option>
  <option value="Pizza2">Carciofi</option>
  <option value="Pizza3">Marinara</option>
  <option value="Pizza4">Funghi</option>
  <option value="Pizza5">Calzone</option>
  <option value="Pizza6">Napoli</option>
  <option value="Pizza7">Romana</option>
  <option value="Pizza8">Quattro Formaggi</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<button type="button" name="button">Toon</button>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="Kiezen()">Kies</button>
```

I did find [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/d6es05zt/) that does this, but not on a button click. Even then, it doesn't work when I add it to my code.

Comment: With `print out`, do you mean actually sending the image to a printer (and also printing nothing but that image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Print out" means "Show", try this

```js
var folder = "https://icco.co.uk/catalog/view/theme/iccqtheme/images/"
function showIt() {
  var pizza = document.getElementById("pizzas").value;
  document.getElementById("pizzaImage").src= folder + (pizza? pizza+".png" : "deliveroo.png");
}
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("toon").addEventListener("click",showIt); // click 
  document.getElementById("pizzas").addEventListener("change",showIt); // or change
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TextVeld" class="form-control"
   placeholder="get value on option select">
</br></br>
<select name="pizzas" id="pizzas" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Kies je pizza</option>
  <option value="piza1">Margherita</option>
  <option value="piza2">Carciofi</option>
  <option value="piza3">Marinara</option>
  <option value="piza4">Funghi</option>
  <option value="piza5">Calzone</option>
  <option value="piza6">Napoli</option>
  <option value="piza7">Romana</option>
  <option value="piza8">Quattro Formaggi</option>
</select>

</br></br>

<button type="button" id="toon">Toon</button>
<button type="submit" name="button">Kies</button><br/>
<img id="pizzaImage" src="https://icco.co.uk/catalog/view/theme/iccqtheme/images/deliveroo.png" />
```